# Setting a value if a condition is fulfilled inside a where condition

Tags: mysql, laravel, if-statement, eloquent

I'm trying the following:

I have a function that returns pubs only if they are open in current moment,

```
/**
 * @param $pubs
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function isPubCurrentlyOpen($pubs)
{
    $pubs->whereHas('pubSchedules', function ($pubs) {
        $pubs->where('week_day', Carbon::now()->dayOfWeek)
            ->whereRaw(
                "'" . Carbon::now('Europe/Madrid')->format("H:i:s") . "' BETWEEN opening_time AND closing_time"
            );
    } );

    return $pubs;
}
```

The problem I have is when some pubs have a closing_time after 00:00 (it would be "next day"), so if I use this function, i.e. 18:00:00, it wont return those pubs.

So, is there any way to make this (setting one more day to closing_time) inside the query statement I wrote before?:

```
if($openingTime>$closingTime)
{
  $closingTime = Carbon::now('Europe/Madrid')->setTimeFromTimeString($schedule->closing_time)->addDay(1);
}
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Provide table structure, If your opening_time & closing_time doesn't contain full date/time then you're doing something wrong

Comment: If your data isn't updated daily (meaning you're storing static data) then it would be fine ... You just have to make up two dates using the difference between the two times e.g: working hours -> convert to dates -> compare

Comment: id| pub_id | week_day | opening_time | closing_time, and Im having problems when week_day = 3, opening_time = 09:00, closing_time = 03:30, for example

Comment: is static data @ahmad...would you give me an example of qhat you're saying? thanks bro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the idea, You might want to create a **MySQL VIEW** to make things easier for you.
And ofcourse it's not very accurate; this is based on a few assumptions given in your question.

```
SELECT *,
CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-', MONTH(NOW()), '-', `week_day`, ' ', `opening_time`) AS `opening_datetime`,
IF(`closing_time` < `opening_time`, 
CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-', MONTH(NOW()), '-', `week_day` + 1, ' ', `closing_time`),
CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-', MONTH(NOW()), '-', `week_day`, ' ', `closing_time`)
) AS `closing_datetime`
FROM `pubSchedules`
```

This would generate a datetime named `opening_datetime` & `closing_datetime` after creating your mysql view you can compare normally without the weekday as you would have 2 full date/times to compare against.

***UPDATE***

Your final query should look something like this (keeping the data I gave in the select)

```
->having('opening_datetime', '>=', Carbon::now('Europe/Madrid'))
->having('closing_datetime', '<=', Carbon::now('Europe/Madrid'))
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! I think it's a great starting point to find a solution...I'll post it (hope soon)Thanks a lot Ahmad

Comment: Ahmad, wath if you can help me here (better explained) Thanks!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968390/error-using-carbon-in-a-query

Comment: If you are not going to create a view, then you'll have to keep those in your select statement & swap your where with having ... forget about week_day in your where statement & use the full date/time to search for the correct answer.